# How to add new tags in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to get the tags from my api. Everything works fine but I cant able to add new tags. Here is what i tried:

```
$(function(){
        var user_email = localStorage.getItem('email');
        var api = localStorage.getItem("user_api_key");
        var auth = "apikey" +' ' +(user_email+":"+api);
        $('#s2id_id_add-places').select2({
            multiple: true,
            tags: [],
            tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
            width: "200px",
            ajax: {
                placeholder: "Click to enter who",
                type: "GET",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
                },
                url: "https://example.com/api/v3/places/",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                processData: true,
                quietMillis: 50,
                data: function(term) {
                    return {
                        term: term
                    };
                },
                results: function(data) {
                    var results = [];
                    if(data.objects.length > 0) {
                        for (i=0; i<data.objects.length; i++) {
                            results.push({id: data.objects[i].id, text: data.objects[i].label, isNew: true});
                        }
                    }
                    return {
                        results: results
                    };
                },
    });
    });
```

By using the above code, I can only get the tags but I cant able to add the new tags. how can i add the new tags?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#e11_2").select2({
  createSearchChoice: function(term, data) { 

      if ($(data).filter( function() { 
           return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0;   
      }).length===0) {
           return {id:term, text:term};
      } 
  },
  multiple: true,
  data: [{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: 2, text: 'task'}]
});
```

You have to create a function like createSearchChoice, that returns a object with 'id' and 'text'. In other case, if you return undefined the option not will be created.

Comment: Where should I create the function createSearchChoice in the code?